# Unable to create a C# object in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-data-factory

I m new to Azure Data Factory. How Can I create a C# object in Azure data factory and I m not sure how we can create an SQL connection in ADF? Somebody please guide me on this?

Comment: *How Can I create a C# object in Azure data factory* You really need to be more specific. I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database?tabs=data-factory#create-an-azure-sql-database-linked-service-using-ui) are an excellent resource when you get started with ADF.

Comment: I m trying to create one ADF Activity which have C# array object.How can i do that ?Is it possible to create object on type array in ADF

Comment: In C# ,string connetionString;
   SqlConnection cnn;
   connetionString = @"Data Source=WIN-50GP30FGO75;Initial Catalog=Demodb;User ID=sa;Password=demol23";
   cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
   cnn.Open();
   MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
   cnn.Close();                                                                                                                                      How we can write the same code in Azure Data Factory

Comment: Azure Data Factory (ADF) provides a GUI to connect to external datasources. Do not expect to be able to connect to a db using c#. See the docs I linked to in my previous comment. ADF is **not** a coding tool.

Comment: Hey @Being Real, why didn't you pick the `Linked service` to connect the Datasource like said by `@Peter Bons`.

Comment: Sure Peter will check the docs you shared @Peter Bons Thank yu

Comment: @RajkumarPalnati-MT Sure will try tat

Answer (score 0):

- Thanks `@Peter Bons` for the valuable suggestions on this.
- Follow the below detailed process to achieve your requirement.

  1. Create an `Azure data factory` from the Portal.
  2. Create SQL Server **&** Azure Storage linked services with   a self-hosted integration runtime.
  3. From the Azure Data Factory Studio launch the Data Factory UI in new tab.
  4. Select the `SQL Server` from the new dataset in pipeline.
  5. Create `New linked service (SQL Server)` and test the connection, it will show you `Connection Successful` once we given all the required values.

***Linked Service Screenshot:***

[image]

***References:***
[Copy data from a SQL Server database to Azure Blob storage by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-portal#create-a-data-factory).

[Create an Azure SQL Database linked service using UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database?tabs=data-factory#create-an-azure-sql-database-linked-service-using-ui).